# Kotlin textSize: different units in get and set

Tags: kotlin, textview, text-size

When accessing the textSize of a textView I do not get same value that I put in there before.

Hello,

I'm new to Kotlin and Stackoverflow.

In a Kotlin app I would like to dimension the size of buttons and textViews depending on the width of the display. So I set the textSize (and others) programmatically. In doing so, I stumbled upon a problem, that I do not understand:

```
    tdp20.textSize = size20before
    var size20after = tdp20.textSize
```

where tdp20 is some textView and size20before is some value (that I got from var size20=tdp20.textSize)

I was surprised to find, that size20before and size20after are NOT equal. Depending on the gsm that I use the values differ by a factor of 1.5 (an old Moto C with Android 7) and 4.0 (realme 8 with Android 12)

I would be very grateful for an explanation.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a weird (and frankly poor) design decision in the TextView class.

You set the text size using SP units, but you get the size back in pixel units.

Here's the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#getTextSize()) for getting text size:

> **returns** the size (in pixels) of the default text size in this TextView.

And here's the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setTextSize()) for setting text size:

> Set the default text size to the given value, interpreted as "scaled pixel" units. This size is adjusted based on the current density and user font size preference.